# virtmanager- Unable to locate libvirtd daemon

Tags: linux-mint, virtual-machine

I tried starting Virt-manager but get this error

```
Unable to connect to libvirt.

internal error: Unable to locate libvirtd daemon in /usr/sbin (to override, set $LIBVIRTD_PATH to the name of the libvirtd binary)
Hi, I tried to start virtmanagerr (installed via mint software center)
but get this?

    Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1027, in _open_thread
        self.vmm = self._try_open()
      File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1009, in _try_open
        flags)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 102, in openAuth
        if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
    libvirtError: internal error: Unable to locate libvirtd daemon in /usr/sbin (to override, set $LIBVIRTD_PATH to the name of the libvirtd binary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting `libvirtd`.

```
$ service libvirtd restart
```

You can check if it's running like this:

```
$ pgrep libvirtd
1124
```

That number is the process ID of `libvirtd`.

```
$ ps -eaf|grep [l]ibvirtd
root      1124     1  0 Mar17 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
```

Comment: why is it more complex than virtual box? :)

Comment: @FutuToad - I use KVM / virt-manager every day, I find it easier actually then virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

I am using debian and i was facing the same issue. I start virt-manager via konsole with the above command and the issue solved.

```
virt-manager --no-fork
```

On this way, virt-manager is asking for ssh password from konsole. Also, provides some output on konsole.